# Which key-value store has decent twisted API (nonblocking)?

Tags: python, nosql, twisted, key-value-store

I need a reliable K-V storage to be run in network. Main requirements:

1. Network connectivity
2. has nonblocking twisted API
3. be reliable, production ready. No data loss
4. write performance is more important than read performance
5. support for distributed operation and failover would be great (So I just specify list of nodes)
6. java/ruby/erlang API would also be much appreciated

Additional bonus for having auto-increment for Key (PK), so SQL (MySQl? Postgres?) are also considered, do they have twisted drivers?

Comment: Did you look at `twisted.enterprise.adbapi` ?

Comment: Thanks for the point, will take a look. But originally I was looking for smth more lite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also Redis, with https://github.com/deldotdr/txRedis. redis is super fast, the only inconveninet is that it is memory based, meaning that your data has to fit in memory.

Comment: Yeah, I found redis to be the best choice so far for many use cases

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB sounds like a really good fit: http://api.mongodb.org/python/1.8.1%2B/index.html

I haven't really played with Twisted yet but Mongo fulfils all of your listed requirements.

Comment: It sounds like twisted driver is not stable. Also it is document store, not plain K-V (BLOB/text) store which creates an overheaad not required in my case.

Comment: Ah oh sorry, I actually missed the k-v bit in the question! In that case I can't really give you much more advice on this one as I haven't played with any of the K-V stores (other than bigtable). Sorry!